# Solr : Counting how many times a word appears in a a line not in a document

Tags: solr, facet

Example :I am fetching data from the DB and the rows looks like below
ID  Age Text

---

```
1 10 Great good very good
2 12 Thanks very thanks good very good
```

What I want from the result is count of good in ID

```
q:good
Facet.query:good
facet.field: ID
```

Result should look like below

```
"facet_counts": {
     "facet_queries": {
     "text:good": 4
},
"facet_fields": {
   "ID": [
      "1",2,
      "2",2,
   }
}
```

What i get is

```
"facet_fields": {
    "ID": [
       "1",1,
       "2",1,
    }
}
```

Looks like its removing the duplicate values in the row ?

Can somebody please help

Schema.xml

---

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Comment: A big thanks to jay ,Here is the answer : `1) use Term vector request handler, 2) search on q:text 3) use all the id's returned from the query for the term, 4) http://localhost:8983/solr/container/tvrh?q=id%3A560647&tv=true&tv.tf=true&tv.all=true' and below is the result

Comment: `<response>
<doc>
<str name="id">686674</str>
<str name="id">560647</str>
<arr name="text">
<str>good</str>
</arr>
<long name="_version_">1506783461943279621</long>
</doc>
</result>
<lst name="termVectors">
<str name="uniqueKeyFieldName">id</str>
<lst name="686674">
<str name="uniqueKey">686674</str>
<lst name="id">
<lst name="560647">
<int name="tf">1</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="text">
<lst name=" ">
<int name="tf">2</int>
</lst>
<lst name="good">
<int name="tf">2</int>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>`

Answer (score 0):

It is not removing duplicate values.

You are getting facets for the field `ID` . According to your query, there are only one document each with `ID=1` and `ID=2` and thats why you get the results 
"facet_fields":

```
{ 
   "ID": 
        { "1",1, 
          "2",1,
        } 
}
```

Your question title and what you have explained in the question are a bit confusing.

Is this line a single document in your solr index? 
`1 10 Great good very good 2 12 Thanks very thanks good very good`

Or these are two different documents:
Document 1

```
{
  ID:1
  Age:10
  Text:Great good very good    
}
```

Document 2

```
{
  ID:2
  Age:12
  Text:Thanks very thanks good very good
}
```

There is no in built way in solr to return the results you are expecting. i.e. return the count of a word inside each document. 
The closest you can get is Term Vector component: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Term+Vector+Component

Comment: Thanks Jay for the answer. The rows are coming straight from one of the table from Oracle DB.    Below is how the rows from the table looks like                                                                                                      Row 1:  1 10 Great good very good                                                                  Row 2: 2 12 Thanks very thanks good very good                                                        So , once the data is tokenized I want to count in row 1, how many  times good exits and same with row 2.

Comment: So "text" is a field per document, and you want to get the count of words in this field per document. Like I mentioned I dont think there is built in functionality for that as of now. The closest you can get is a list of terms in that field per document using the term vector component. So the best option I can see if to run two queries. First query will give you all the words per document. Once you have that you will have to one query per document to solr like this ```q=id:1&facet=true&facet.field=text&facet.mincount=1``` , this will give you count of each word in that one document.

Comment: Thanks again Jay, Sorry I might be sounding Dumb here, are you referring to one row as one document?

Comment: BTW, check the answer I finally was able to solve the problem with your help...Thanks a lot Jay :)